# Loader icon in Bot Framework Webchat

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am using Bot Framework Webchat. There are few user related data which I am posting using back channel post activity through the `store` option to greet the user.

```
<ReactWebChat
  activityMiddleware={ activityMiddleware }
  directLine={ window.WebChat.createDirectLine( this.state.token ) }
  store = {this.handleGetStore()}
  styleOptions={styleOptions}
/>
```

`handleGetStore` returns the store data:

```
handleGetStore(){
    const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
        if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
            dispatch({
                type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
                payload: {
                    name: 'userDetail',
                    value: this.state.userDetail
                }
            });
        }
        return next(action);
    });
    return store;
}
```

When the connection initiates the loader appears.

[image]

After that there is delay of about 3-5 seconds before the welcome message appears and in the meantime the Webchat seems ready for the user.

[image]

A slight delay of 3 seconds is acceptable but quite often the delay is upto 10 seconds or more. I understand that this can be slightly improved by using the `Always On` feature of the App Service and scaling up the plan. Is there a way I can wait for the back channel welcome message to appear and show the loader until then?

Reference: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/pull/1866

Comment: Can you add the code you are using to send the welcome event?

Comment: @tdurnford Added the implementation of `handleGetStore`

Comment: So your issue is that the welcome event is being sent and the bot responds with the welcome message while the connecting spinner is still being displayed, even though you are sending the welcome event after the connection is fulfilled from the store’s middleware?

Comment: @tdurnford No. The spinner goes off but there is a delay in receiving the welcome message. The second snapshot I attached above shows the spinner is gone and the welcome message is yet to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the connection status display relies on events received from DirectLineJs and Web Chat does not support customizing its behavior at the moment. That being said, there is a hacky way to accomplish what you're trying to do by dispatching pseudo DirectLine events.

Here are the steps below:

- Create a flag that will indicate whether or not the bot has sent a welcome message - `received_welcome_message`.
- When Web Chat dispatches a connection fulfilled event, check the flag
  to ensure a welcome message has been received. If the bot has not
  sent a welcome message, dispatch the welcome event to the bot and reset the
  connection status to fulfilling.
- When Web Chat receives an activity
  from the bot, check if it is a welcome message. I would recommend
  adding a name attribute to message on the bot side to check - `await
  context.sendActivity({ text: 'Welcome', name: 'welcome'})`. If the
  activity is a welcome message, dispatch a connection fulfilled event and set the flag to true.

For more details take a look at the code snippets below.

```
let received_welcome_message = false;
const store = createStore(
  {},
  ({ dispatch}) => next => action => {

    if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {

      if (!received_welcome_message) {
        dispatch({
          type: 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLING'
        });
        dispatch({
          type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
          payload: { name: 'webchat/join' }
        });

        return
      }

    } else if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY' && action.payload.activity.name === 'welcome') {
      received_welcome_message = true;
      dispatch({
        type: 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED',
      });
    }
    return next(action);
  }
);
```

## Edit

A less hacky approach is to dispatch a post activity pending event when the connection to the bot is fulfilled to mimic the bot sending a welcome message. Note, that the bot is unaware of the mimicked activity. See the code snippet below.

```
const store = createStore(
  {},
  ({ dispatch}) => next => action => {
    console.log(action)
    if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
      dispatch({
        type: 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY_PENDING',
        meta: { method: 'keyboard' },
        payload: {
          activity: {
            from: { role: "bot" },
            text: "Welcome Message",
            textFormat: "plain",
            timestamp: new Date().toString(),
            type: "message"
          }
        }
      })
    }
    return next(action);
  }
```

Hope this helps!